# Pair key/value : call a method key with params , returns value constructed with params

Tags: java, constructor, enums, mapping

Imagine this mapping in this pseudo language

```
class Mapping{
  key0 --> new ObjectValue()
  key1 --> new ObjectValue()
  key3 --> new ObjectValue1(String name)
  key4 --> new ObjectValue2(String name, int age)
  ...
}
```

In this mapping , values are instanced by different constructors. When I call any key, I want to pass some parameters.

**Constraints :** <s>All keys extend from a common class.</s> 
All ObjectValues extend from a common class.

---

I want the method calls to return

```
StaticMapping.key0.get();  //  return new ObjectValue()    
StaticMapping.key1.get(name);  //  return new ObjectValue1(String name)
```

**How to accomplish this ? What is this pattern ?**

---

AFAIK the data structures **Map** , [enum constructor](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Useanenumconstructorinstancevariableandmethod.htm) cannot achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my question  , I originally posted I want to call methods such as

```
StaticMapping.key0.get();  //  return new ObjectValue()    
StaticMapping.key1.get(name);  //  return new ObjectValue1(String name)
```

but the structure doesn't have to be a Map.

I found a simpler solution with static methods in a proxy class .

```
public class InstanceMap {
    public static ObjectValue KEY0(){
        return new ObjectValue();
    }

    public static ObjectValue1 KEY1(final String name){
        return new ObjectValue1(name);
    }

    public static ObjectValue2 KEY4(final String name, final int age){
        return new ObjectValue2(name, age);
    }
}

// method call
InstanceMap.KEY0();
InstanceMap.KEY1(name);
```

Note : ObjectValue2 and ObjectValue1 extend from ObjectValue

Hope this helps others as well.

Comment: Nice, but this does not fill _your_ constraint of _"All keys extend from a common class"_. That would have been a lot easier :P

Comment: No, I thought of those constraints . Good point, I will re-edit in the OP. 
True , the answer would have been right in front of the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Because all the keys have a different interface, most importantly, *with differing numbers of arguments*, you would have to define a new type for each key.

The fact that they have to have a common super type, also forbids the use of interfaces from `java.util.function`, as static types.

```
class KeySuper {...}

class KeyType0 extends KeySuper {
    public ObjectValue get() {
        return new ObjectValue();
    }       
}

class KeyType1 extends KeySuper {
    public ObjectValue1 get(String str) {
        return new ObjectValue1(str);
    }       
}

// Simmilar for KeyType2

class StaticMapping {
    // public static final Supplier<ObjectValue> key0 = ObjectValue::new;
    // ^^^ does not have the common super type...

    public static final KeyType0 key0 = new KeyType0();
    public static final KeyType0 key1 = new KeyType0();
    public static final KeyType1 key2 = new KeyType1();
    public static final KeyType2 key3 = new KeyType2();
}
```

---

There are other options like, taking in an `Object[]`, and at runtime, checking the number and type of arguments, throwing an exception if they're not correct, just so you can have an:

```
abstract ObjectValue get(Object...);
```

defined on the super type, which doesn't really seem that useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not fan of varargs . In your StaticMapping class , how can you pass an argument ?

Comment: @RaymondChenon You would pass the arguments when calling ```get```.